# Restricting a plot to be over integers

Tags: plotting, summation, piecewise

I am trying to plot the following function:

```
Plot[
  Sum[
    {{100 + x}, {n}}*0.82^n*(1 - 0.82)^(100 + x - n)*
      Piecewise[
        {{341*(100 + x), n <= 100},
        {341*(100 + x) - 900*(n - 100), n > 100}}],
    {n, 0, 100 + x}],
  {x, 0, 40},
  PlotRange -> Full]
```

And I need $x \in \mathbb{N}$, I tried with `DiscretePlot[]`; however, I get a list of errors, which I will not list here because they are many.

Edit:

When I try to evaluate the function for $x=0$ I get 2 values, why so?

```
F[x_] := Sum[{{100 + x}, {n}}*0.82^n*0.18^(100 + x - n)*
 Piecewise[{{341*(100 + x), 
 n <= 100}, {341*(100 + x) - 900*(n - 100), n > 100}}], {n, 0, 
 100 + x}]

F[0] = {{0.0105141}, {0.0104846}}
```

Comment: @Bill I get the following error:

Syntax::sntxf: "Table[" cannot be followed by "Sum....

Comment: You get two values because {{100 + x}, {n}} is a vector of size 2, so you are summing lots of different 2-vectors in your Sum.

Comment: You're getting two values because you're summing `{{100 + x}, {n}}`, which is a list of two lists, with each of those containing a number. If you don't want two values, what is the comma for in `{{100 + x}, {n}}'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question, it is not clear what you want to do. Most probably you want to

1. make a plot where the x and y coordinates are the two terms in your summation or
2. you want to plot both of them as a function of x.

In both cases, you can use `Table` with `ListPlot`.

```
data=Table[Sum[{100+x,n}*0.82^n*(1-0.82)^(100+x-n)*Piecewise[{{341*(100+x),n<=100},
         {341*(100+x)-900*(n-100),n>100}}],{n,0,100+x}],{x,0,40}]
```

**1**

```
ListPlot[data,PlotRange->All]
```

[image]

**2**

```
ListPlot[Transpose[data],PlotRange->All]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DiscretePlot` if you first change `Sum` to `First@Sum` or `Last@Sum`. (It wasn't clear to me which you wanted.)

Comment: Seriously: keep exactly what you have except for two changes: change `Plot` to `DiscretePlot`, and change `Sum` to `First@Sum`.